# Como alineo los datos en le pdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

Quiero montar una factura le problema es que los datos no me salen tabulados me sale todo junto. He conseguido sacar todoo pero al meter en uan misma variable precio y producto queda unidos y no puedo meter espacio para tabular el precio y que se vea uno debajo de otro.este es mi codigo

```
<?php

include 'conn.php';
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
require'Pdf/fpdf.php';
foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $codigo => $producto) {
    $mData.="$producto[titulo] $producto[precio] euros \n";
    $mTotal += round($producto['precio']/1.21,2);
    $iva += round($mTotal*.21,2);
    $total += $mTotal+$iva;
}
$a ="Subtotal factura:      ";
$subTotal= $a.$mTotal;
$s ="iva:                              ";
$ivaT = $s.$iva;
$d ="Total factura:            ";
$totalf= $d.$total;
$n = random_int(1, 99999);

class PDF extends FPDF {

// Cabecera de página
    function Header() {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('imagenes/a.jpg', 10, 8, 33);
    }

}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(100, 20, '', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->setX(50);
$pdf->Cell(60, 10, '      Factura numero:  ', 0, 0, 'c');
$pdf->Cell(100, 10, $n, 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, $_SESSION['name'], 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, 'avenida Guerrita 27', 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(90, 10, 'Cordoba', 0, 1, 'l');
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Moviles Carod', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Cif:B8065792', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Avenida de la Concepcion 32', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Madrid', 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->MultiCell(90,10,$mData,0,"L");
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, $subTotal, 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, $ivaT, 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, $totalf, 0, 1, 'R');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

asi se ve mi "factura"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hace mucho que no trabajo con `FPDF`, de hecho, desde que descubrí `DOMPDF`, porque te permite armar un PDF desde código HTML+CSS y resulta muy fácil generar casi cualquier tipo de documento.

Comment: UF me ha costado muchisimo el fpdf como para pasarme a dom ahora jaj si eres capaz de armarmelo te lo agradezco en el alma soy muy novato en php mi profesor no explica ni me ayuda dice que investigue (con decirte que estoy tabulando a mano con espacio el nombre y el precio en la BD

Comment: ¿Como de cuánto estamos hablando? No, compadre, la idea es que aprendas a hacerlo por ti mismo y, como te dije, es muy fácil, solo tienes que armar una página HTML y pasarla a DOMPDF, incluso con tablas para evitarte los problemas que tienes ahora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías separar `$mData` en 2 variables, una para producto y otra para precio, y montar 2 celdas contiguas, en lugar de ir a la siguiente línea en cada una.

Se trataría de cambiar:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(90,10,$mData,0,"L");
```

Por:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cesta'] as $codigo => $producto) {
    $prod_tit = $producto[titulo]; $prod_pre = $producto[precio]." euros";
    $pdf->Cell(50,10,$prod_tit,1);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10,$prod_pre,1);
    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

El ancho de cada celda y el aspecto ya lo ajustas según los contenidos que vayas a mostrar. Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.